# Spring-boot web and public resources

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

From my understanding, ONLY the files located in the folders:

```
src/main/resources/public
src/main/resources/static
```

are served statically by the web server.

So if these two files contain sensitive configurations, are they safe in this location (not exposed by the web server) ?

```
src/main/resources/ultra_secret.xml 
src/main/resources/nasa/alien_list.xml
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ONLY the files located in the folders:

No. The list is [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content).

> are they safe in this location (not exposed by the web server) ?

By a process of elimination, yes.